# The props not changing the background button color

Tags: typescript, react-native

## Objective

I am trying to switch the background color button if the `off` props are passed. Something like, if the button contains de off, the background color button will `red` and if not contains, the background color will `green`.

## What happening?

I am passing the props but the color not change and the two buttons that I have stay green.

## Code

### Home

```
<ContainerRow>
<Button onPress={handleConnectBluetooth}>Conectar</Button>
    <Button onPress={handleDesconnectBluetooth} off={false}>
        Desconectar
    </Button>
</ContainerRow>
```

Here the button with the text `Desconectar` needs to be red.

### Button component

```
import React from 'react';
import {RectButtonProperties} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import {Container, ButtonText} from './styles';

interface ButtonProps extends RectButtonProperties {
  children: string;
  off?: boolean;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({children, off, ...rest}) => (
  <Container off {...rest}>
    <ButtonText>{children}</ButtonText>
  </Container>
);

export default Button;
```

Here the props `off` inside the parameters, say `off is defined but never used`.

### Button style

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import {RectButton} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

interface IButtonProps {
  off: boolean;
}

export const Container = styled(RectButton)<IButtonProps>`
  height: 40px;
  background: ${(props) => (props.off ? '#29ed1f' : '#ff0000')};
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

export const ButtonText = styled.Text`
  color: #312e38;
  font-size: 18px;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your Button Component

```
const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({children, off, ...rest}) => (
  <Container off {...rest}>
    <ButtonText>{children}</ButtonText>
  </Container>
);
```

React docs clearly explain that:
[Props Default to “True”](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true)

> If you pass no value for a prop, it defaults to true. These two JSX expressions are equivalent:
>
> ```
> <MyTextBox autocomplete />
> <MyTextBox autocomplete={true} />
> ```
>
> In general, we don’t recommend not passing a value for a prop, because it can be confused with the ES6 object shorthand `{foo}` which is short for `{foo: foo}` rather than `{foo: true}`. This behavior is just there so that it matches the behavior of HTML.

Correct code:

```
const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({children, off, ...rest}) => (
  <Container off={off} {...rest}>
    <ButtonText>{children}</ButtonText>
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: I tried your response but the button with the text `Conectar` painted with the red color, I need that the button `Desconectar` will red

Comment: I fixed the problem about the color using `background: ${(props) => (props.buttonDesconect ? '#ff0000' : '#29ed1f')};`, your answer helped a lot, thanks